# A simple probability problem on runs

Tags: probability

Let us consider arrangements of $a$ many $x$'s and $b$ many $y$'s with each arrangement equally probable. Show that
$$ \Pr(\text{exactly }k\text{ runs of }x\text{'s occur})=\frac{\dbinom{a-1}{k-1}\dbinom{b+1}{k}}{\dbinom{a+b}{a}} $$

What I tried :
Firstly, Let the number of $x$'s in the runs be $x_i$. So we have to solve for $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k=a$ where $x_i\gt 0$. Number of solutions to this is $\dbinom{a-1}{k-1}$. Now, the rest is confusing me. How did the $b+1$ term come? I also tried to see the other binomial co-efficient as $\dbinom{b+1}{b+1-k}$ but it still doesn't help. Can someone tell me what to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: After you choose your $k$ strings of $a$, there are $k+1$ places where strings of $b$ could go (either the beginning, or the end, or any of the $k-1$ places in between the runs of $a$), and the first and the last strings of $b$ can have $0$ $b$'s while the rest of the $k-1$ runs of $b$ in between the $k$ runs of $a$ must have at least $1$ $b$. If you have variables in a sum that are allowed to be zero, this is the same as adding 1 to the sum for each such variable and then computing the number of ways to get positive integer solutions, because then you can subtract one from each variable that is allowed to be zero and recover the original sum. See "stars and bars" construction and generalizations if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: So it is like solving the equation $y_1+y_2+\dots+y_{m-1}+y_m=b$ where $y_1,y_m\ge 0$ and rest are positive. Then we get the desired answer!! Thanks a lot. :)